# Styling a C/C++ file on diffs

Tags: c++, git, astyle

I have a requirement to style only the part of the C/C++ file which is getting committed (so the blame for the other lines are intact). Is there any tool to just do that? I know we can style the whole file and get the blame to ignore styling changes (but my team doesn't want that).

Here are a few things I tried with [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/):

1. I write the diff to a new file and style it and replace the diff part in the original file - Why it doesn't work? It doesn't really get styled as it doesn't have the context, like the if statement to indent the rest of the lines on etc.
2. I style the whole file and replace only the section that changed. - Why it doesn't work? If I try to change max code length and the lines get broken up then the diff lines are different.
3. How about a 3 way merge between the original file and the file where the styled diff is included?  Yet to try this.

May be there is an easier way and I am missing it :S

Comment: What do you mean _"style"_ the git file history will show what has changed and who committed it?

Comment: Is this really a problem worth solving?

Comment: @RichardCritten Coding guidelines like indent spaces/tabs,k&r style etc.

Comment: @You The short answer is, you are right... maybe not! Thanks.

Comment: `git` doesn't commit just the changed portions of a file. It commits the entire contents, every time. How it eventually _stores_ it is a different matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a git hook and clang-format.

For example this: https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/git-clang-format

Comment: I for one won't be following that link (since my browser flags its cert). Via google I did find clang-format docs which *claim* to be able to format a unified diff; but I'm more than a little skeptical that this would address the issues OP raised regarding things already tried, since the example usage in the docs shows no means of conveying the context to clang-format